# C++ Assignment not compiling with G++ but is on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++

This is a very rushed assignment, just a few days ago my laptop had died with all of my progress so I had little time to make everything with this work.

I am having a (what feels like big) error with compiling my project with G++. Especially when i did all of my testing on visual studio (and had no errors)

I would run
`g++ -std=c++11 ksim.cpp -o test`

I believe that the error is connected to my two-dimensional arrays, but am not 100%.

Is there a setting inside of Visual Studio that I am missing to check how its compiling everything?

```
// Nathan Vassell
// CS 245 - Assignment 4


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <sstream>

/*#include <locale>*/
using namespace std;

// Global variables
int ticks = 0;
string userInput;
string processes[256];
string blockedProcesses[10][3];
queue <string[10][3]> blockedQ2;
queue<string> newQ;
queue<string> readyQ;
queue<string> runningQ;
queue<string> blockedQ;
queue<string> exitQ;


int main()
{

    return 0; 
}
```

The Error im getting

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/deque:62:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/queue:60,
                 from ksim.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Des                                                                                                                                                             troy(_Tp*) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char> [10][3]]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_construct.h:103:46:   required from ‘static void                                                                                                                                                              std::_Destroy_aux<<anonymous> >::__destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator)                                                                                                                                                              [with _ForwardIterator = std::basic_string<char> (*)[10][3]; bool <anonymous> =                                                                                                                                                              false]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_construct.h:127:27:   required from ‘void std::_                                                                                                                                                             Destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = std::basic_                                                                                                                                                             string<char> (*)[10][3]]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_construct.h:151:31:   required from ‘void std::_                                                                                                                                                             Destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_T2>&) [with _Forward                                                                                                                                                             Iterator = std::basic_string<char> (*)[10][3]; _Tp = std::basic_string<char> [10                                                                                                                                                             ][3]]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/deque.tcc:807:31:   required from ‘void std::deque<_                                                                                                                                                             Tp, _Alloc>::_M_destroy_data_aux(std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, std::deque<_                                                                                                                                                             Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char> [10][3]; _Alloc = std                                                                                                                                                             ::allocator<std::basic_string<char> [10][3]>; std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator                                                                                                                                                              = std::_Deque_iterator<std::basic_string<char> [10][3], std::basic_string<char>                                                                                                                                                              (&)[10][3], std::basic_string<char> (*)[10][3]>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_deque.h:1853:39:   required from ‘void std::dequ                                                                                                                                                             e<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_destroy_data(std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, std::deque<_T                                                                                                                                                             p, _Alloc>::iterator, const std::allocator<_CharT>&) [with _Tp = std::basic_stri                                                                                                                                                             ng<char> [10][3]; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> [10][3]>; std:                                                                                                                                                             :deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Deque_iterator<std::basic_string<char> [10                                                                                                                                                             ][3], std::basic_string<char> (&)[10][3], std::basic_string<char> (*)[10][3]>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_deque.h:918:62:   required from ‘std::deque<_Tp,                                                                                                                                                              _Alloc>::~deque() [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char> [10][3]; _Alloc = std::al                                                                                                                                                             locator<std::basic_string<char> [10][3]>]’
ksim.cpp:19:23:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_construct.h:93:7: error: request for member ‘~st                                                                                                                                                             d::basic_string<char> [10][3]’ in ‘* __pointer’, which is of non-class type ‘std                                                                                                                                                             ::basic_string<char> [10][3]’
     { __pointer->~_Tp(); }
       ^
-bash-4.2$
```

Comment: Please, don't post images with text. (Copy/paste the text instead.)

Comment: Please post your code (ksim.cpp)

Comment: ...or even better: Please, try to reproduce your issue in a [mcve].

Comment: Without actual code it's hard to see what's happening. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I will add the changes

Comment: You clearly didn't read the article [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ... again.
BTW the error messages are now missing so it's quite hard again to know what's wrong.

Comment: Everything should be good now, minimal code and the error message

Comment: @FroyoJones : Hint : the line causing problems is `queue <string[10][3]> blockedQ2;
`

Comment: And `std::queue` has requirements on what you can put into a queue.

Comment: @Cedric Should i use a different type of queue for that? I kind of figured it would be a problem, but I dont get why it still compiles in visual studio.

Comment: It's working since gcc 10.1 with -std=c++20, see [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4sqhKb)

Comment: Turns out Im just a fool and `queue <string[10][3]> blockedQ2;` wasnt even needed, I just forgot to remove it haha

Comment: @FroyoJones The requirements are a bit "hidden" imho. The default container of `std::queue` is `std::deque`, which has the requirements of "Erasable" since C++11. This is roughly [described](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Erasable) as "With the default allocator, this requirement is equivalent to the validity of p->~T()". Notice the similarity to your error. One way to solve this would be to use e.g. `std::array` instead of the C array.

Comment: @FroyoJones That also solves the problem :D